Missing argument in the proof of the Levy-Khintchine representation .
In one proof of the Levy Khintchine representation of the Laplace exponent of subordinators, the following argument is used:
"Assume  $f_n : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is a sequence of non-increasing functions such that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} f_n(x) dx \; \text{ converges towards a finite value as } \; n \to \infty \text{ for each }\;  \lambda \geq 0,$$
then necessarily the limit has the form
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} (\alpha \delta_0(x) + f(x) dx) = \alpha  + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} f(x) dx$$
for some $\alpha\geq 0$ and some non-increasing function $f$."
How to prove this statement ?
It is quite unusual to be able to say anything about the "densities" under such a weak convergence statement. But the non-increasing assumption is crucial here.

Hopefully there is a more concise answer. I will prove much more than required, namely that $f_n(x) dx$ converges in distribution towards $\delta_0(dx) + f(x) dx$ with $f$ decreasing, and that $f_n \to f$ on every point of continuity of $f$. The idea will be to use the existence results for the moment problem.
Write $g_n(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x} f_n(x) \mathrm dx$, then for every $\lambda\geq 0$, as $n\to\infty$ we have $g_n(\lambda) \to g(\lambda)$.
The derivatives of $g_n$.
Write $h^{(k)}$ for the $k$-th derivative of function $h$. We can easily check that $g_n$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ with
$$ g_n^{(k)}(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty (-x)^k f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx . $$
A bound on the moments of $f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x}$.
Since $g_n(t) \to g(t)$ for every $t$ we have $A(t) := \sup_n g_n(t) < \infty$.
Fix $\varepsilon>0$. For every $k$, the maximum of $x^k e^{-\varepsilon x}$ is attained for $x=k/\varepsilon$ and equals $e^{-1} k^k \varepsilon^{-k}$, so that for every $\lambda>\varepsilon$ and every $n$,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^k f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx \leq e^{-1} \varepsilon^{-k} g_n(\lambda-\varepsilon) \leq e^{-1} k^k \varepsilon^{-k} A(\lambda-\varepsilon) . 
\end{equation}
The fact that $f_n$ is non-increasing allows us to write
$$ tf_n(t) \leq \int_0^t f_n(x) dx \leq g_n(0) \leq A(0) . $$
Then, for $0<\lambda\leq\mu$,
\begin{equation}
|g_n^{(k)}(\lambda) - g_n^{(k)}(\mu)| \leq \int_0^\infty x^k \frac{A(0)}{x} (e^{-\lambda x} - e^{-\mu x}) dx \leq (\lambda^{-k} - \mu^{-k}) A(0) k! .
\end{equation}
The derivatives of $g_n$ converge to those of $g$.
We then proceed by induction. Assume that $g_n^{(k)} \to g^{(k)}$ for some $k\geq 0$ — this is the case for $k=0$. Since $(-1)^k g_n^{(k+2)}$ is non-negative, $(-1)^k g_n^{(k+1)}$ is increasing. Then for every $0<s<t<u$ and every $n$, we have
\begin{multline} 
(-1)^k g_n^{(k+1)}(t) - A(0) k! (t^{-k} - u^{-k}) \leq (-1)^k g_n^{(k+1)}(u) \\\\
\leq (-1)^k\frac{g_n^{(k)}(u) - g_n^{(k)}(t)}{u-t} \leq (-1)^kg_n^{(k+1)}(t) \leq (-1)^k\frac{g_n^{(k)}(t)-g_n^{(k)}(s)}{t-s} \\\\
\leq (-1)^k g_n^{(k+1)}(s) \leq (-1)^k g_n^{(k+1)}(t) + A(0) k! (s^{-k} - t^{-k}) .
\end{multline}
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, we first have
$$ (-1)^k\frac{g^{(k)}(u) - g^{(k)}(t)}{u-t} \leq (-1)^k\frac{g^{(k)}(t)-g^{(k)}(s)}{t-s} $$
as well as
$$ \left| \frac{g^{(k)}(u) - g^{(k)}(t)}{u-t} - \frac{g^{(k)}(t)-g^{(k)}(s)}{t-s} \right| \leq A(0) k! (s^{-k} - u^{-k}) ,$$
which together allow us to conclude that $g^{(k)}$ is differentiable in $t$. In addition, by the squeeze theorem, we have $g_n^{(k+1)}(t) \to g^{(k+1)}(t)$.
Existence of a limiting measure.
For every $n,N$, the $N\times N$ matrix $H(n, \lambda)$ where
$$ H(n,\lambda)_{i,j} = \int_0^\infty x^{i+j} f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx = g_n^{(i+j)}(\lambda) $$
is positive semi-definite, see here. We have $H(n,\lambda) \to H(\lambda)$ as $n\to\infty$, where $H(\lambda)_{i,j} = g^{(i+j)}(\lambda)$. Since the eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously on its coefficients, we deduce that $H(\lambda)$ is also positive semi-definite, thus that it is the Hankel matrix of a measure: hence, there exists $\mu_\lambda$ such that
$$ g^{(k)}(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty x^k \mu_\lambda(d x) . $$
Connexion between the $\mu_\lambda$.
The moments of $\mu_\lambda$ determine it uniquely. Indeed, by our previous estimates, for every $0<\varepsilon<\lambda$
$$ \int_0^\infty x^k \mu_\lambda(dx) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty x^k f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx \leq e^{-1} k^k \varepsilon^{-k} A(\lambda-\varepsilon) . $$
Thus they satisfy Carleman’s condition.
We can then use the Fréchet-Shohat theorem to conclude that $f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx \to \mu_\lambda$ in distribution.
In particular, since $x \mapsto e^{-\mu x}$ is continuous and bounded on $[0,\infty)$ for every $\eta \geq 0$, we have that for every $h$ continuous and bounded
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\eta x} h(x) f_n(x) e^{-\lambda x} dx \to \int_0^\infty e^{-\eta x} h(x) \mu_\lambda(dx) $$
as $n\to \infty$, but we also have that it converges to $\int_0^\infty h(x) \mu_{\lambda+\eta}(dx)$. Since this holds for every continuous and bounded test function $h$, we conclude that for every $\lambda, \eta>0$, $\mu_{\lambda+\eta}(dx) = e^{-\eta x} \mu_\lambda(dx)$.
This leads us to observe that for every $t < \lambda$, we have $\int_0^\infty e^{+t x} \mu_{\lambda}(dx) = g(\lambda-t) < \infty$. By the monotone convergence theorem, taking the limit as $t\to\lambda$, we get
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{\lambda x} \mu_\lambda(dx) = \lim_{t\to\lambda} g(\lambda-t) = g(0) < \infty . $$
It follows that there exists a finite measure $\mu_0$ with total mass $g(0)$ such that for every $\lambda>0$, $\mu_\lambda(dx) = e^{-\lambda x} \mu_0(dx)$. In addition, using the monotone convergence theorem we can also show that $f_n(x) dx \to \mu_0(dx)$ as $n\to\infty$.
Note that $\mu_0$ is not guaranteed to have any finite moment, so we cannot directly construct it like the other $\mu_\lambda$.
Towards the representation of $\mu_0$.
The dominated convergence theorem gives that $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} g(\lambda) = \mu(\{0\})$.
Consider a non-negative, continuous and bounded function $\rho$ with support in $[0,1]$ and with integral $1$. For every $0<s<t<u$, by
$$ f_n(s) \leq \int_s^t f_n(x) \frac{1}{t-s} \rho\left(\frac{x-s}{t-s}\right) dx \leq f_n(t) \leq \int_t^u f_n(x) \frac{1}{u-t} \rho\left(\frac{x-t}{u-t}\right) dx \leq f_n(u) $$
and taking the limit as $n\to\infty$,
$$ \int_s^t \frac{1}{t-s} \rho\left(\frac{x-s}{t-s}\right) \mu_0(dx) \leq \liminf f_n(t) \leq \limsup f_n(t) \leq \int_t^u \frac{1}{u-t} \rho\left(\frac{x-t}{u-t}\right) \mu_0(dx) . $$
Taking $\rho$ that approaches the indicator function of $[0,1]$, then $s\to t$ and $u\to t$, we can deduce that $x\mapsto \mu_0([x,\infty))$ has a left and right derivative $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ that is non-negative and non-increasing, and $f_n \to f$ wherever $f$ is continuous.

Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer Thomas !
